# How to capture the Right-Click event in the other workbooks by VBA/Excel

Tags: vba, excel, right-click

After add the following code to the *ThisWorkbook* object in Excel, it can successfully capture right-click on any worksheets in the current workbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeRightClick(ByVal Sh As Object,  ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
   MsgBox "OK"
End Sub
```

However, could you please suggest if it is possible to to capture right-click event from another workbook?

**Case**

There is a xlam file to store all scripts for a VBA project. In the *Thisworksheet* object of the xlam file, I added the following events

```
'1) add popmenu when open any new workbook
' It works fine
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call addPopMenu
End Sub

'2) delete popmenu when close a workbook
' It works fine
Private Sub WorkBook_Close()
    Call deletePopMenu
End Sub

'3) Capture the right-click event before displaying popmenu
'It does not work
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    'Call CheckPopMenu(Target) 'Aims to set the pop-menu based on the value in the cell
    MsgBox "OK"
End Sub
```

**Issue**

The pop-menu was added successfully to new Excel workbooks by *code (1)*. Unfortunately, *code (3)* could not be invoked when right-click on any new Excel workbooks. As a result, I not able to update the pop-menu based on the values in the cells.

Is there anyway to make it works? Thanks.

**Update**

The suggestion from Mat's Mug works well. Any credit should goes to Mat's Mug.

The following is my Working code based on the suggestion of Mat's Mug. Hope it will be helpful to people who troubled the issue

1) Add  the following "xAppClass" class module to the VBA project

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents ExcelAppEvents As Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
     Set ExcelAppEvents = Application
End Sub

Private Sub ExcelAppEvents_sheetBeforeRightClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
   Call CheckCellMenu(Target)  'replace with your own function
End Sub
```

2) add the following code to a module

```
Public exlApp As New xAppClass
```

3) In the 'ThisWorkbook' object, add

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set exlApp = New xAppClass
End Sub
```

After add the above code and run the "Workbook_open" routine, right-click is now able to update the pop-menu on worksheets for all workbooks.

Comment: You need a reference to the other workbook, and if you want to handle that other workbook's `SheetBeforeRightClick` event then you need that object to be declared `WithEvents`. Note: won't work if the other workbook is in another instance of Excel.

Comment: @NoahHu Instead of updating your question through the comments, you can [update the original question here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46534094/edit).

Comment: Dear Mat, Thank you very much. Your suggestion has successfully solved the issue.