# Is there a way to have BeforeRightClick act upon an Active Workbook and not the book containing that code?

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to find a way to trigger a code from my Personal.XLSB BeforeRightClick event when making a right click within an Active Workbook, other than my Personal.XLSB

What is the way to make it happen?

Tried to do it, but to not much surprise it does not trigger.
Maybe you know...

Comment: Perhaps using [Application-level events](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/events/excel-application-level-events.htm)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46534094/how-to-capture-the-right-click-event-in-the-other-workbooks-by-vba-excel for how to set this up.

Comment: hmm... Wonder if it has caveats, like if I have different code running from within specific workbooks, also triggered by BeforeRightClick... @TimWilliams

Comment: Well you can easily try that out...  In a quick test, a worksheet-level right-click handler and the application event-linked one both fired when right-clicking the sheet.